# How to process comma separated string of ids using Mono<String>

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, flux, reactor

I have a api which gives me a list of comma separated ids and I am using Spring Boot WebClient to make a call to the same and process the response.

The API response is [1,2,3,4] in plain/text (not json) and I am doing the following to process the results -

```
Mono<String> ids = client.get()
                .uri("http://localhost:8080")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
```

I wanted to know how can I process the items inside the ids variable from thereon.

newbie to this api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert response directly into `Flux`, and process items one by one

```
webClient.get()
        .uri("http://localhost:8080")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(Integer.class)
        .doOnNext(id -> {
            System.out.println(id);
            // process id...
        })
        .subscribe();
```

Another possible option is to convert `Mono<String>` into `Flux<Integer>` using method `flatMapIterable`:

```
ids.flatMapIterable(line -> Arrays.asList(line.replace("[", "").replace ("]", "").split(",")))
        .doOnNext(id -> System.out.println(id))
        .subscribe();
```

Comment: The first fails with error cannot cast to integer as the content type is plain/text. I tried converting it to String.class but it still outputs it as a complete string not one by one as its plain/text. The 2nd is giving syntax error

Comment: `The 2nd is giving syntax error` - on which part you have syntax error? have you added `import java.util.Arrays;`?

Comment: Thanks. That worked. my mistake. Also one more follow up question - inside doOnNext() i make 2 calls to 2 separate APIs and get 2 Mono<String> which I then zip into one final Mono. Now is there a way for me to return this final Mono back as a Mono<ServerResponse>

Comment: something similar to: `Mono<String> yourFinalMono = ...;
        yourFinalMono.flatMap(line -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(line, String.class));`